# Can I weigh without a set of scales?

Tags: measurements, measuring-scales

So I'm at my sister's house, and it turns out she doesn't have any scales.

I need to weigh 120g of castor sugar.

What can I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This site](http://convert-to.com/sugar-products-weight-volume-amounts-conversion) will convert weights to volumes, and says that you should use .53 of a US cup.

Comment: Great find Neil - I was going to suggest water displacement or creating a quick and dirty fulcrum/balance beam and comparing it to objects of known weights - but .53 cups is SO much easier!

Comment: mad props to anyone who can eyeball .53 cups.

Comment: 1/2 a cup is easy. Get out your half cup measure. 0.03 cups is just 1.44 teaspoons. I'd probably go sloppy and use a teaspoon and a half.

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out she doesn't have any volume measurements either, other than a measuring jug.

So in the end I divided the 500g bag between two identical glasses, then divided one of those glasses up between 2 others to get approx 125g

Now it seems that the cake tin doesn't seal properly anyway so I can't imagine that my cheescake is going to turn out any good anyway...

For Neil, a measuring jug:

[image]

Comment: Way to innovate.

Comment: Nice solution. What's a measuring jug?

Comment: @Neil added a picture of a measuring jug for you

Comment: That's the same thing we call a measuring cup. I had an image of a literal jug in my head. (The image was in my head, not the jug.)

Answer (score 2):

[Gourmet Sleuth](http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/) can help you with its advanced conversion calculators.

For example, a teaspoon of baking powder does not weigh the same as a teaspoon of peanut butter. [This calculator](http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/cooking-conversions/gram-conversions.aspx) will simply give you an approximate measurement. **When accuracy is imperative you should use the highly-accurate ingredient based calculator.**

[Weight To Volume Conversion Calculator](http://www.gourmetsleuth.com/cooking-conversions/cooking-conversions-calculator.aspx) shows that 120 gr sugar (powdered) = 1.2 cup or 48 teaspoons.

Just enter "sugar" as keyword and select "sugar, powdered" under "sweets" menu. Then enter the quantity, select conversion unit and click "Convert". On the left panel, you can see the results.

Comment: Powdered sugar is denser than castor sugar.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [Wolfram Alpha](http://wolframalpha.com) for this, for example [`120 gram/density of sugar/cups`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=120+gram/density+of+sugar/US+cups).

Although, they don't have castor sugar in their system.